# Replace jQuery on() with native javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jQuery code which attaches click eventhandler to dynamically added elements having an custom attribute named "data-my-attribute".

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-my-attribute]', (event) => { this._handleClick(event); });
```

How can I replace this jQuery code with native/vanilla javascript?

Comment: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#delegate

Comment: If you need a custom attribute, [follow the standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)